# JPAAppender blob

Tags: java, jpa, log4j2

I am testing the log4j JPAAppender these days. After hours of work, I encountered just as same problem as others did.(if you search for JPAAppender, you will get that the log4j JPAAppender got a bug which keeps persisting garbage of a column of blob in size is huge for database). After that, I tried to download the source code from its official website and rewrote my own code which has exactly same class name and all the same functions in source code apart from a tiny modify I made to avoid entitymanager persisting garbage into database.

```
@Transient
private final LogEvent wrappedEvent;
```

here it is as you can find in log4j 2.7,package 
`package org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa;`

After doing that with full of hope that I might make it right, I ran my application and I got this error:

```
2018-01-29 17:18:44,543 main ERROR Entity class [com.log4jtest.demo.logger.JpaLogEntity] does not extend AbstractLogEventWrapperEntity.
```

So, what can I do? I really wanna use this appender.

maybe you might do the following, I will appriciate it:
1. tell me how to extend my own class without the error ocured
2. maybe you have got some brilliant solution, pls share.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your `com.log4jtest.demo.logger.JpaLogEntity` should extend `AbstractLogEventWrapperEntity`? That's what the error seems to complain about, so what's the matter?

Comment: Do you have a ticket for this bug? I couldn't find any evidence of a bug like that.

Comment: no, I have changed JpaAppender with JdbcAppender. I don't think I could fix it on my own, so unless apache fix it, I would not rist trying to use it again. ps. JdbcAppender with slf4j's MDC combination perfectly solved my problem. anyway ,thanks for reply.